# Maintain java mapping from two different types of values in a single data structure

Tags: java

I have a collection of objects that look something like

```
class Widget {
  String name;
  int id;
  // Intuitive constructor omitted
}
```

Sometimes I want to look up an item by name, and sometime I want to look it up by id.  I can obviously do this by

```
Map<String, Widget> mapByName;
Map<Integer, Widget> mapById;
```

However, that requires maintaining two maps, and at some point, I will (or another user who is unfamiliar with the double map) will make a change to the code and only update one of the maps.

The obvious solution is to make a class to manage the two maps.  Does such a class already exist, probably in a third party package?

I am looking for something that lets me do something along the lines of

```
DoubleMap<String, Integer, Widget> map = new DoubleMap<>();
Widget w = new Widget(3, "foo");
map.put(w.id, w.name, w);
map.get1(3); // returns w
map.get2("foo"); // returns w
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be, to write your own key class that includes both keys.

```
class WidgetKey {
  String id;
  String name;
  boolean equals() {...}
  boolean hashCode() {...}
}

Map<WidgetKey, Widget> yourMap;
```

Beware that you have to implement equals and hashCode in the WidgetKey class. Otherwise put/get and other map methods wouldn't work properly.

Comment: How would you implement them?

Comment: It sounds that the id and the name are unique. If this is the case just use `Map<Object,Widget> ` and `put` each widget twice into that same map. You can have a class wrapping all this which exposes a single `add(Widget)` and two gets

Comment: For "equals" and "hashCode" there are several ways to implement.

1. Use your IDE to generate them
2. Use 3rd party libs like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang with EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder
3. Do it by hand

Comment: I fail to see how this would work.  I suppose you could implement hashCode as `return 0` and equals as `return this.id.equals(other) || this.name.equals(other)`, but that is unorthodox.  When I am trying to get something out, I only have one of the two key values.

Comment: If you use HashMap as implementation of Map, implementing `hashCode() return 0` is no good idea, as the hash value is used as primary key inside HashMap. Have you take a look at commons-lang library? Or if you don't want a new dependency have you tried to let it be generated by your IDE?